# unable to connect to local instance of jupyter notebook in google colab ubuntu 18.04

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I followed the steps given in [link](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html) to connect to a local instance of jupyter notebook. I was able to connect in a windows system but I am unable to do the same in ubuntu 18.04 system. The error msg is as below.

```
Failed to execute cell. Could not send execute message to runtime: SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

The detailed error msg is

```
The operation is insecure.
Cz@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:1362:93
Bz.prototype.fetch/<@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:1361:114
za@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:528:334
xa.prototype.next_@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:526:387
Ca/this.next@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:529:204
Ea/<@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:530:83
Ea@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:529:505
w@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:530:117
Bz.prototype.fetch@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:1361:60
Bz.prototype.get/<@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:1360:95
za@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:528:334
xa.prototype.next_@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:526:387
Ca/this.next@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:529:204
Ea/<@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:530:83
Ea@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:529:505
w@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:530:117
Bz.prototype.get@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:1360:50
h.getKernelSpecs/<@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:2757:94
za@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:528:334
xa.prototype.next_@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:526:387
Ca/this.next@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:529:204
Ea/<@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:530:83
Ea@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:529:505
w@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:530:117
h.getKernelSpecs@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:2757:49
b1/<@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:2795:163
za@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:528:334
xa.prototype.next_@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:526:387
Ca/this.next@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:529:204
Ea/<@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:530:83
Ea@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:529:505
w@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:530:117
b1@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:2794:279
n3@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:2906:414
ZY.prototype.connect@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:2910:357
p3/<@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:2908:365
za@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:528:334
xa.prototype.next_@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:526:387
Ca/this.next@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:529:204
Ea/<@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:530:83
Ea@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:529:505
w@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:530:117
p3@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:2908:171
MP/<@https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180906-085300-RC00_211815267:2928:180
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you encountering this error when using Mozilla Firefox? If so, you may need to set the `network.websocket.allowInsecureFromHTTPS` preference. See the "Browser-specific settings" of the local runtimes documentation for more details: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html.

Note: You'll need to configure this setting on each system.

If this doesn't fix the problem, would you mind posting a few more details including:

- Browser version used
- Browser network logs
- Any output from console where your Jupyter notebook instance is running

Comment: I am using Google Chrome browser Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit). I am not sure what resolved the issue, I am able to connect to the local instance of jupyter notebook now. May be restarting the system might have helped.